# PHP , CURL get the body responses

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL link that returns(body response) a status either 1 or 0.
I have been searching a lot and I didn't get the idea of cURL how to get it as a php
I want to connect it with the php so, ***I can take the status and use it as a condition in php***.
The cURL has an Access Token and Authorization: Bearer , I hope you got the idea so you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function I use.  It sends over an array of parameters and values (an associative array) and gets the result back.  (In my case, it should be JSON.)

```
function do_curl_function($array, $url = "http://url.com") {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'myusername:mypassword');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result) {
        $result = json_decode($result);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I may use it like:

```
<?php
    $post_array = array("action" => "subscribe", "name" => "James", "email" => "my@email.com");

    $result = do_curl_function($post_array);

    if ($result) {
       print_r($result);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why we should do it as a function?And what is the benefit of using an array? And should I use the commented things or just leave it?

Comment: You don't need the commented area.  I have it in my code in case I need it in the future.  The array contains "fields" I'm posting to the URL.  If you have to post data to the other page you will need to use the array.  If not, you can comment out the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` line altogether.  I'll update my code to show you an example.  You do not need to use it as a function if you do not want to.  However, it makes things easier for the most part.

Comment: Please see the updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$url = "www.url.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/json","Accept:application/json",and some Authorization);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo $result
echo $info

if ($result) {
    $result = json_decode($result);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

?>

I did it like that and the HTTP response was 200 OK but, when I echo the result and the info its print string "array" while expecting to print 1 or 0.

It seems to me that it needs to Get The body response so I can get the result, I hope u understand what I mean.

Comment: You really should have just edited your original post instead of adding this as a question (so it's not confusing to other visitors).  However, you would not need the `$result = json_decode($result);` line since you are not expecting a JSON string back.  Also, this line should be removed: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/json","Accept:application/json",and some Authorization);` or at least changed to not be application/json because you are not expecting a JSON response.